Can the number of wasted cycles per branch misprediction vary greatly? And why?
When learning about the basic 5-stage pipeline processor that does in-order execution the number of wasted cycles per branch misprediction is a constant number when the processor is flushed.
But what about a multi-issue out-of-order modern processor with a deep pipeline? For class we are running simulations of different programs on a processor and the number of wasted cycles per misprediction varies greatly depending on the program for the same processor, in some cases only 10 wasted cycles per misprediction, but in some cases over 100 wasted cycles pre misprediction. Which is much larger than the pipeline depth. I would expect a number close to the pipeline depth and independent of the program run.
I have been trying to come up with an explanation for this. I understand that in modern processors branch evaluation may happen at different stages, so the number of wasted cycles is not constant. But I can't explain why this difference can be an order of magnitude larger for different programs. Does the processor "know" which instructions need to be flushed?
Can the number of wasted cycles for modern processors vary greatly and be dependent on the program? If so how is this possible? And how can the difference be so large between different programs?

How are you measuring the branch misprediction cost.  I'm not up to date on my latest architecture, but I'm curious if a misprediction that results in a memory load cache miss, followed by a (correct path) memory load cache miss might lead to an extremely long delay by tying up the main memory bus.

That's a good question. The simulator is a bit of a black box for me and I have been trying to find how it measures the misprediction cost. We are simulating the processor using SESC, but documentation is hard to find...

You have to be aware that modern processors can accomplish (or attempt to accomplish) many many instructions in one cycle.  Thus, the number of cycles that are wasted might be small, yet cycle count doesn't necessarily reflect true waste of misprediction.

I'll take a stab at this one.
The number of wasted cycles for out-of-order execution in a multi-core architecture will exceed the pipeline's depth because reordering requires extra effort.
Branching in modern speculative cores can discover the misprediction at different stages (e.g., ID vs. EXE vs. MEM), which leads to a different number of wasted cycles after a misprediction. In-order processors generally have a fixed stage when mispredictions are solved, so the number of wasted cycles is constant.
With an out-of-order processor, the point at which a branch is resolved can vary, so the number of wasted cycles can vary. Also, remember that Out-of-order processors that execute instructions speculatively, depending on the depth of speculation when a misprediction is discovered, could lead to many more wasted cycles.  One branch that is speculated may lead to other branches that are speculated.  This will not be the same for every program, and the penalty for out-of-order will differ.
Additionally, predictor accuracy, code density, parallelism, and access patterns play a role.  Consider sequential access, where the memory order will respect the program order.  Does each program have the same access pattern?  How many threads are used program-to-program?  Cache Locality (spatial, temporal)? Certain data structures are more cache-friendly than others; misprediction cycle penalties can differ because of the different number of hits vs misses when solving a misprediction. (e.g., linked lists have poor locality while arrays locality is good).

With the reordering, what do you mean with that? I don't think we have covered that in class yet. I think the most plausible explanation so far is that there is some cache / mem latency involved and thats why wasted cycles can vary so greatly. In some programs due to worse locality the cycle penalty would be bigger.
